# Length of Sequence with limitations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

There are 4 components (k1, k2, k3, k4). 
a) How many sequences are there of length 1000?

I know that the number of strings of length n with k elements is k^n, so 4^1000.

b) There is the same amount of k1 as there is of k3 and the same amount of k2 as k4, but there is 3 times the amount of k2 as k1. How many such sequences are there of length 1000?

I'm so lost on how to do this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You know that every letter is either $k_1,k_2,k_3$, or $k_4$. If $a_1,a_2,a_3$, and $a_4$ denote the number of times the respective letters are in your sequence, this means $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=1000$. But now we additionally know that $a_1=a_3$, $a_2=a_4$, and $3a_1=a_2$. Plugging this in gives 
$$
8a_1=1000
$$
or $a_1=125$. So we know there are $125$ copies of $k_1$ and $k_3$, and $375$ copies of $k_2$ and $k_4$. Of your $1000$ letters, first choose the $125$ locations where $k_1$ will be, then out of the remaining $875$ choose $125$ more for the $k_3$, and then finally choose where the $k_2$ will go; the remaining slots are forced to be filled with $k_4$.

Answer (score 0):

If there are
$m$ k2s,
then there are
$m$ k4s
and
$3m$ k1s and
k3s.

The total number of items
is $3m+m+3m+m
= 8m
=1000$,
so $m=125$.

The k2s can be in
$\binom{1000}{125}
$ positions.
The k1s can be in
$\binom{1000-125}{3\cdot 125}
=\binom{875}{375}
$ positions.
The k3s can be in
$\binom{875-375}{3\cdot 125}
=\binom{500}{375}
$ positions.
The k4s are in
the remaining positions.

The total number of possibilities is

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{1000}{125}\binom{875}{375}\binom{500}{375}
&=\dfrac{1000!}{125!875!}\dfrac{875!}{375!500!}\dfrac{500!}{375!125!}\\
&=\dfrac{1000!}{125!^2375!^2}
\end{array}
$